# How do I fix Launchpad not saving icon order settings?

Tags: icon, bug, launchpad

I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6, and Launchpad is not saving my icon order when I log out. Only happens on my account, it works fine for other users in the same machine.

Some webpages say I should delete a database file in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock`, but the only file there is `desktoppicture.db` (which does not affect the icons in Launchpad). I also tried deleting the db files in `$TMPDIR../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad` with no success.

I can rearrange icons and it will appear to work for as long as I'm logged in. But when I log out, icons return to the same order as if I reset dock with the `ResetLaunchPad -bool true` setting. In fact, the directory `$MPDIR../0/com.apple.dock.launchpad/db` is rewritten whenever I `killall Dock` (new inodes).

I can't find any other thing to do. The only thing I've noticed is that when I killall Dock, I get a weird message in console:

```
MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree:73: Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported
```

I don't know if that's unimportant or if it's got something to do, but it sounds like a corrupt file and I don't know where to look for it.

I ran out of ideas, I can run any commands or send whatever info is needed, please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to do that but there is an $8 app named Launchpad Manager Yosemite.app that runs on Yosemite and higher.  I'm using it on high Sierra. You can get a free version but its pretty limited. the paid app will sort your launch pad alphabetically or you can sort it manually any way you like.

Comment: Yes, I tried that app, it doesn't work when I click "Apply" :(

Comment: interesting. i put them in order and it worked fine for me.

Comment: When I click apply, it says the database will be overwritten and Dock will be restarted. But for some reason Dock doesn't read the database, instead it overwrites it, losing the changes made by the app.